# Promise.reject() continues with then() instead of catch()

Tags: node.js, promise, browserify, es6-promise

I am making myself a library which retries failed promise "chain-parts" - I collect methods to be called and queue next phase only after previous succeeded.

Conceptually rounded up - my problems are more fundamental. This is where I arrived with debugging:

```
this.runningPromise
    .then(function() { 
        return Promise.reject();
    })
//;
//this.runningPromise
    .then(this.promiseResolver.bind(this))
    .catch(this.promiseRejector.bind(this))
    ;
```

Works, `promiseRejector` kicks in. When I uncomment out the two lines, works not. `promiseResolver` gets called.

Can't find anywhere anything. Nodejs 6.10.3 with browserify on Windows, Chrome.

Comment: Chaining does not mutate the original promise, it returns a new one. When you are chaining multiple `.then()` calls on the same `this.runningPromise`, then you are *branching* the control flow.

Comment: Unacceptable best answer. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you uncomment two rows means you are calling `this.runningPromise` twice and each time it has its own callbacks.

If you keep the rows commented then it will act as a promise (and associated callbacks)

Better you should assign promise to a variable and then you can use it multiple times.

```
let newPromise = this.runningPromise
    .then(function() { 
        return Promise.reject();
    });

newPromise
    .then(this.promiseResolver.bind(this))
    .catch(this.promiseRejector.bind(this));
```

With above code you can use `newPromise` multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

`this.runningPromise` will not change when you chain other callbacks, i.e. the promise referenced by `this.runningPromise` was never rejected. So you have to assign the *new* promise to a new reference:

```
let something = this.runningPromise
    .then(function() { 
        return Promise.reject();
    });

something
    .then(this.promiseResolver.bind(this))
    .catch(this.promiseRejector.bind(this));
```